# Firebase firestore function deploy failed due to unexpected token "." optional chaining

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy node.js trigger and functions with code that contains optional chaining. I previously deployed this code without error, but now am facing this error:

```
return this.roles?.includes(role.toString()) ? true : false; 
                  ^ 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/diwimaModelWeb/lib/network/index.js:13:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

I use typescript and the build target as configured in tsconfig.ts is "es2020". I could go through the code and replace all the optional chaining with null cheking, but I'd rather not because I previously deployed it without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having this issue. I fixed it during writing this question myself, I noticed that I was using different node and npm verisons for building and uploading, nvm is tricky like that :D. Also I selected "es2017" in tsconfig. Not 100% sure what fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was indeed the mismatching node version.
(Not npm though, that shouldn't matter).

Steps for resolving:

1. Check your local node version: `nvm --version`
   (in case you installed manually from their website I'd suggest starting to [use nvm](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-node-version-manager) now :)
2. Make sure the same is set in your `package.json`,
   e.g. `"engines": {"node": "14"},`
3. Set your ES version in your `tsconfig.json` as needed.
   e.g. `"target": "ES2020",` it should be compatible with your node version.
   A list of [ES versions' feature highlights](https://www.quikieapps.com/blog/ecmascript/) here and the list of [node versions supported by firebase here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version).

Optionally, if you still have issues:

4. Make sure everything mentioned so far is in the `functions` folder of your firebase app (and for example you didn't install dependencies in the root folder by accident).
5. Check and update firebase-tools and firebase packages if needed. e.g. `npm install --save firebase-functions`
6. Delete `package-lock.json` then build + deploy again (`npm run lint && tsc` and `firebase deploy --only functions`). Chances are some of your dependency installations got messed up, e.g. you didn't --save them (at least I did that while trying to solve the initial problem in the previous step).